# Django - template not loading, perpetual 302 message

Tags: python, django

I am getting the following on my command line when my server is running and I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/terms`:

```
[19/Jun/2015 18:09:04]"GET /terms HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jun/2015 18:09:05]"GET /terms HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jun/2015 18:09:05]"GET /terms HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jun/2015 18:09:06]"GET /terms HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jun/2015 18:09:07]"GET /terms HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jun/2015 18:09:07]"GET /terms HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jun/2015 18:09:08]"GET /terms HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[19/Jun/2015 18:09:08]"GET /terms HTTP/1.1" 302 0
```

This kind of output continues perpetually until I quit/exit the server session manually.

I am not sure why this is happening. I am pretty new to Django so maybe I overlooked something obvious.

Here is my `terms` view in `views.py`:

```
def terms(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return redirect(terms)
```

This is my route for `terms` in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^terms/', 'my_app.views.terms'),
```

I have also created a `terms.html` template in my templates folder with some dummy text.

Why is this not working?

I know there is simpler ways to do this but I want to know why this particular way doesn't work. I am trying to understand how to put conditional statements in the views that use the requests library for some more complicated things I have to do later on in this project.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTTP status code 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) is for redirects. You appear to be redirecting from `terms` back to `terms` and creating an infinite loop.

Do you mean to be redirecting? If so, where do you mean to be redirecting to?

You can redirect to an object:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    object = MyModel.objects.get(...)
    return redirect(object)
```

Or to another view:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('some-view-name', foo='bar')
```

Or to a relative URL:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('/some/url/')
```

Or to an absolute URL:

```
def my_view(request):
    ...
    return redirect('http://example.com/')
```

Check out the [redirect docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) for more info.

If you didn't mean to redirect, you probably want to `return` one of the following: [HttpResponse()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse), [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), or [render_to_response()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response). Be sure to specify your template (`terms.html`) within in the view with these.

For even less work, use [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/).

Comment: Thank you! This got me going in the right direction. I ended up having to use render or render_to_response for this. Thanks!